# Determine degree of field extension $\mathbb{F}/k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with $8$ elements und $k$ a prime field. ($1$st task) Determine the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{F}/k$. ($2$nd task) Is there an $a \in \mathbb{F} \backslash k $ with $a^3\in k$ so that the following is true $\mathbb{F}=k(a)$?

As I am currently studying for my algebra exam I decided to use old algebra exam exercises to practice, but this exercise is rather tough.

- First task

So my answer for this is that for a finite field, there are $p^r$ elements with $r\in \mathbb{N}$, where $p$ is a prime number. So logically speakin we have:

$p^r=8 \rightarrow p=2; r=3$

And the the degree of the field extension should be defined as

$\mathbb{F}/k:=\text{dim}_\mathbb{K}(\mathbb{F})=\{3\}$

Is this correct?

- Second task

Unfortunately  I don't know how to begin solving this, so maybe someone could give me hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many elements in the multiplicative group? Thus what can you say about the inverse of the map $b\to b^3$?

Comment: The first answer is OK. For the second, the only possible values of $a$ are 0 or 1, and  the polynomial $x^3-a$ is not irreducible for this values.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm asking, but would you mind elaborating? A path on how you reached that conclusion would be very helpful ^^